# Kotlin; subtract a value in current object from a value in previous object and put in a new object

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of nozzleState objects which are sorted by nozzleStateDate. The data class like below

```
data class NozzleState(val shiftId: Int, val nozzleValue: Int, val nozzleId: Int, val userId: Int, nozzleStateDate: String)
```

I need to subtract the latest object's nozzleValue from its previous object's nozzleStateObject
I have this piece of code by now but I don't know what to do next:

```
val nozzleSaleReport = nozzleStateList
                .sortedByDescending { item-> item.nozzleStateDate }.groupBy {
            it.nozzleId}
```

In other words if there are

```
(10, 8, 6, 3)
```

for the nozzleValue field in the list the result would be

```
(10-8, 8-6, 6-3, 3-0)
```

Comment: might be [reduce](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/reduce.html) that you're looking for

Comment: Would you please provide an example?

Comment: just by looking at the last two shown lists, I would assume that [`zipWithNext`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip-with-next.html) is your friend... (only that last `3-0` might not work out of the box ;-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nozzleSaleReport` does not help in this case. 
If `nozzleStateList` is already sorted by `nozzleStateDate` **ascending** then you need:

```
val dif = nozzleSortedList.last().nozzleValue - nozzleSortedList[nozzleSortedList.size - 2].nozzleValue
```

If `nozzleStateList` is not sorted then you need first to sort it **descending**:

```
val nozzleSortedList= nozzleStateList.sortedByDescending { it.nozzleStateDate }
val dif = nozzleSortedList[0].nozzleValue - nozzleSortedList[1].nozzleValue
```

In any case you must check that the size of the list is at least 2. 
Also since `nozzleStateDate` is a `String`, it must be in the proper format, 
like `yyyy-MM-dd` so it is comparable and the sorting will be done correctly.
Edit
To apply the subtraction to all the items in the list you can do this:

```
nozzleStateList.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
    if (index < nozzleStateList.size - 1)
        item.nozzleValue -= nozzleSortedList[index + 1].nozzleValue 
}
```

**but** you must change the definition of `nozzleValue` in the data class from `val` to `var`.

Comment: Could I use fold or reduce?

Comment: Why? This is only 1 subtraction. It does not apply to all or several items in the list.

Comment: Actually it does apply to the list: for example if there are (10, 8, 6, 3) for the nozzleValue in the list the result would be (10-8, 8-6, 6-3, 3-0)

Comment: *I need to subtract the latest object's nozzleValue from its previous object's* what do you mean by that?